# Cannot ping .local machines on one computer

Tags: linux, avahi

I have the following three computers connected to my home network:

- a Mac Mini running Lubuntu 13.10 (`macmini`)
- a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian 7 (`raspberrypi`)
- a Compaq Mini running Lubuntu 12.04 (`compaqmini`)

Avahi is installed and running on all three computers and from `raspberrypi` and `compaqmini` I can ping the other two hosts (with the `.local` suffix). On the Mac Mini, however, `ping raspberrypi.local` and `ping compaqmini.local` gives me an "unknown host" error message. Any clues? How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: how do you connect them over a wireless router or over lan and router, or do u use a switch/hub?

Comment: Check if Avahi is really running and check your /etc/nsswitch.conf.
On hosts: line it should contain mdns_minimal (or mdns4_minimal in case of IPv4-only network).

Comment: How are you expecting the Mac mini to convert those names to IP addresses?

Comment: @konqui The macmini and raspberrypi is wired to my broadband modem (which is also a WiFi router). The compacmini is connected wirelessly to the same modem/router.

Comment: @piernov Avahi is running but the hosts line in /etc/nsswitch.conf says `hosts: files dns`. I tried changing the line to `hosts: mdns_minimal` and then to `hosts: mdns4_minimal` (restarting avahi-daemon after each edit) but it made no difference.

Comment: @piernov It turned out I needed to install `libnss-mdns` as well. Now it works. If you turn your comment into an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lubuntu 13.10 Avahi is not configured to handle `.local` domains by default. To solve the problem, install the package `libnss-mdns` and (as mentioned by piernov) in the file `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, change the line

```
hosts: files dns
```

to

```
hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```